# How to detect text view begin editing and end editing in swift 3

Tags: swift, textview

I found related questions and answers in objective-c but I couldn't find a proper way to this with swift? Is there methods to detect for text view same as text filed in swift?

I want to solve the issue hiding text view by keyboard. For that I need a way to detect start and end edit text view.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Note: I'm using swift 3.

Comment: Use the delegate methods for UITextView.

Answer (score 13):

Just as Bawpotter said, "Use the delegate methods for UITextView". Here is what they look like in Swift 3:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

  // Run code here for when user begins type into the text view

}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

  // Run code here for when user ends editing text view

}
```

Also make sure your UITextView's delegate is set to `self` or wherever these methods are in your app

Answer (score 4):

Conform your ViewController class to UITextViewDelegate and then write 
`textView.delegate = self` in your viewDidLoad(). After that write delegate methods for your textView as:

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
     //  your code here
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    //  your code here
}

func textViewShouldEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
     //  your code here
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) { 
   // your code here
}
```

Comment: You can also refer to this link for detail information: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate