# Issue with updating Edited Textview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a `textView` and i need to update my `textView` content and save the edited text. In my case everything is working but in the UI edited text is updated.self.taskName data get it from the previous ViewController

In `viewDidLoad` i was written like this

```
self.taskNameTextView.text = self.taskName
self.taskNameTextView.delegate = self
```

In `textViewDelegate`,

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        self.taskName = textView.text
}
```

and button action i have to passed the edited textString and it return successful but not changed updated text in UI.Can you please anyone help me to figure out this problem.

Comment: Didn't quite get your question.Could please edit it

Comment: what is `self.text`?

Comment: You wrote `self.textView.text = self.text` in `viewDidLoad:` so it will be call when you come forward to this `viewController`. While `self.text` is not a global string so it will be nil at the loading time. You need a global variable might be declared in `AppDelegate` or in `Sinlgeton` class.

Comment: @CtrlAltDel i am edited my question.

Comment: @Kuldeep self.text,that text data stored from the previous view controller

Comment: While clicking on button where do you want to pass the edited string?

Comment: I have an popup view in selecting the UITableview Cell,inside that popup passing the selected cell taskName data,after updating the data should be displayed in UITableview Cell.

Comment: you didn't paste any code related to tableview, and also after dismissing the popup what are you doing? it would be better if you could paste some more code

Comment: After dismissing just close the view.Ok i will update my code

Comment: if you are editing some value in a tableview you need to reload the tableview

Comment: Am reloaded tableview,but it's called but the edited data only not updated in UITableview.

Comment: show me your code to update the cell data after dismissing the popup and your cellforrowindexpath code

Answer (score 0):

Rather than textViewDidChange please write your code inside

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) { 
// your code here
}
```

For more delegate functions of TextView please refer to this post;

[How to detect text view begin editing and end editing in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476216/how-to-detect-text-view-begin-editing-and-end-editing-in-swift-3)